# Name for the image in different iOS versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, icons

is there a way to name the images/icons which I use in my app somehow to use different icons in ios6/7?

For example I try to use:

```
bar_item-ios7@2x.png
bar_item@2x.png
```

And I would like Xcode automatically use the first one when I launch the app in ios7 and the second one in ios6. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't offer support for that, but one workaround could be to use a category for UIImage with a method that loads the right version based on the OS version:

```
+(UIImage)imageNamed2:(NSString *)imageName{
    NSString *finalImageName;
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7){
        finalImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ios7-%@",imageName];
    }else{
        finalImageName = imageName;
    }
    return [self imageNamed:finalImageName];
}
```

This way, the images would be named:

```
example.png
example@2x.png
ios7-example@2x.png
```

And you can instantiate the image this way:

```
[UIImage imageNamed2:@"example.png"];
```

Hope this helps